# How to set virtual property inside an async instance method

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I have an Article model and am trying to set a virtual 'comments' property to an array of comments. I was hoping to have use an instance method which gets the comments using `$look-up`. I imagine this could be done with populate but i want to avoid doing using this as it requires 2 seperate queries of the database.

Here is the instance method:

```
articleSchema.methods.getComments = async function () {
    const result = await this.constructor.aggregate([
        {
            $lookup: {
                from: Comment.collection.name,
                let: { articleId: '$_id' },
                pipeline: [
                    {
                        $match: {
                            $expr: { $eq: ['$$articleId', '$articleId'] },
                        },
                    },
                    { $sort: { date: -1 } },
                    { $limit: 10 },
                ],
                as: 'comments',
            },
        },
    ]);
    console.log(this, 'comments', result.comments);
    this.comments = result.comments;
```

And here is where i define the virtual

```
articleSchema.virtual('comments', {
    ref: 'Comment',
    localField: '_id',
    foreignField: 'articleId',
});
```

For some reason the `console.log` of results shows the array of objects for the `comments` property. But `console.log(result.comments)` returns undefined. I guess this is why my setting on `results.comments` onto `this.comments` isn't working.

Does anyone have any idea why this might be.

Obviously there are other approaches i can take, like simply returning the result and sending this to the client which works, but i am curious as to why the above is happening.